# Simple program that automatically compiles latex file

Tags: macos, bash, latex, texmaker

I am using a unix based OS and i am at moment trying to make a small bash program that compiles my tex file all the time, such that i don't need to do that every single time.. the It seem to be compiling fine, but it doesn't create any PDF file.. and I am bit confused on why it doesn't do that.

Here is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode /Users/Johnathan/Documents/Bachelor/Rp/bachelor.tex
done
```

Comment: Use [rubber](http://www.usinglinux.org/textproc/rubber.html) ... See http://www.usinglinux.org/textproc/rubber.html

Comment: not sure what you mean.. Exactly this code has worked before.. which why i am asking

Comment: Oh I misread, sorry. I suggest using inotifywait  (https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)  to compile the tex files every time the content changes or use a cron job. -- Does the command generate a pdf when manually executing it?

Comment: Anything useful in the log file?

Comment: It says that no error occurs and a PDF should be created but none are created.. this was intended to be some kind of cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the bash.. I forgot to run it in correct directory.. I kept it had outputted the onto start..